# android-xml parsed XML data fetch problem

Tags: android, xml, parsing

how to fetch a perticular tag data from parsed XML file in android??
i have multiple sub tags in my XML file 
any help???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe expand your question a little? At any rate sounds like you just want to use the [SAX parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) and the [StartElementListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/sax/StartElementListener.html) to listen to the particular tag starting and then just extract its value.